# Copy Data From OdbcConnection to SQLStatment

Tags: c#, sql

I want to copy my data from OdbcConnection to SqlStatment thru C# code. Thru one button I want to do this...
I'm not much expert in c# but just little bit programming, can some one add/edit some codes our statement/help so i can complete my program.

I do thru this code but data is not fetching....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private OdbcConnection cn;
private SqlCommand DB_Cmd;
private SqlConnection DB_cn;
public const string DbConStr = "Data Source=172.16.4.8;Initial Catalog=anDb;User ID=sa; Password= ;";
private OdbcCommand Jda_Cmd;
//private long Jda_Order_no;
public const string JdaConStr = "DSN=Imports_Img;UserID=user2;Password=pass2;Data Source=172.16.4.5;Transport Product=Client Access;SSL=DEFAULT;DEFAULT COLLECTION='BINDAWOOD'";
//private string sku;


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.cn = new OdbcConnection();
    this.Jda_Cmd = new OdbcCommand();
    this.Jda_Cmd.Connection = this.cn;
    this.cn.ConnectionString = "DSN=Imports_Img;UserID=JUNAID;Password=PAKIKARA19;Data Source=172.16.4.5;Transport Product=Client Access;SSL=DEFAULT;DEFAULT COLLECTION='BINDAWOOD'";
    string str = ("SELECT ibhand FROM MM410LIB.INVBAL WHERE INUMBR = 79610 AND ISTORE=14");
    this.Jda_Cmd.CommandText = str;
    {
        this.cn.Open();

        OdbcDataReader reader2 = this.Jda_Cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //connection2.Open();
        while (reader2.Read())
        {
            this.DB_Cmd = new SqlCommand();
            this.DB_Cmd.Connection = this.DB_cn;
            SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection();
            //SqlCommand db_cn = new SqlCommand ("insert into invbaldb ('sku') values ('" + reader2[0] + "')", connection2);

            //SqlCommand db_cn = new SqlCommand("insert into invbaldb (sku) values ('" + reader2[0].ToString() + "')", connection2);

            SqlCommand DB_cn = new SqlCommand("insert into invbaldb (sku) values (@sku)", connection2);
            DB_cn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sku", reader2[0].ToString());

            //SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("insert into invbaldb ('sku') values ('" + reader2[0] + "')", connection2);
            //DB_cn.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DB_cn.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        reader2.Close();
        //connection2.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the destination field inside the table `invbaldb` is named `sku` then you shouldn't put single quotes around that name because in that way is interpreted as a literal string

```
  SqlCommand db_cn = new SqlCommand ("insert into invbaldb (sku) values ('" + 
                                      reader2[0].ToString() + "')", connection2);
```

Also consider to use a parameterized query instead of a string concatenation.

```
  SqlCommand db_cn = new SqlCommand ("insert into invbaldb (sku) values (@sku)", connection2);
  db_cn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sku", reader[0].ToString());
```

**EDIT** If the destination field is numeric, then the parameter should be typed accordingly

```
  db_cn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sku", Convert.ToInt32(reader[0].ToString()));
```

of course this means that the input value is something that could be converted to an integer value

Comment: its mean should i use this?

'                SqlCommand DB_cn = new SqlCommand("insert into invbaldb (sku) values (@sku)", connection2);
                DB_cn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sku", reader2[0].ToString());'

instead of 
'SqlCommand db_cn = new SqlCommand("insert into invbaldb (sku) values ('" + reader2[0].ToString() + "')", connection2);'

Comment: Well, yes, parameterized queries are generally considered a better choiche than executing a string concatenation. For example, if your reader[0] contains a string with a single quote, the string concatenation builds an invalid sql statement. There is also concerns for Sql Injections though, in your case, is improbable.

Comment: I think my problem almost solve, but can you please tell me the data which is receiving is numbers only like "233425"...

Really appreicated Mr. Steve, really lot of thanks...

but can you tell me I use "int" instead of string.

Comment: What datatype is expected by the field `sku`? If this field is an integer then you need to convert the value passed as parameter value. In your original code you put the single quotes around the value of reader[0] and this means that you pass a string.

Comment: Yes in SKU....

It means the data from ODBC is numerical value only.
odbc is actually DB2, i create connection in odbc so the data came from As400/JDA.

and i want to put this figures like SKU which came from INVBAL

its in numerical "2344" or "2233" like this...

|Sorry for distrube you bcoz I don't have much knowledge regarding c#|

Thanking You (I'm now pasting complete code in Answer side)